# Is there a centrally maintained list of phones / tablets and OS combinations that could guide a sensible list of devices to test on

Tags: ios, testing

I am trying to construct an up to date device matrix for our dev teams that lists the mobile devices that we should target.

This is a question that I see come up over an over again. I appreciate that there is no ideal device matrix as each project will have its own requirements, but I think that it could be easy to say that the most popular devices and OS' such as iPhone 5 and iOS 7 would be included as they are a market leading device and OS combo.

Other devices such as iPhone 3Gs would have fallen off the list because now it is just not a significant device in the market.

Ideally the matrix should include Android and iOS phones and tablets.

In general I am looking for one that captures the majority of the market but excludes those that are not worth testing for.

Are there any resources that present this in an up to date clear consumable format?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devices, take a look at the [iOS Support Matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com).

Comment: Thanks nielco, while that is a useful matrix for visualising the compatability of iOS versions with iPhone device versions, it does not tell me what devices are worth testing due to their significance in the market.

Comment: @JetB You can infer that from the relative percentages of each iOS version and then match that up with the devices supported by that version. For example, [iOS 7 adoption is currently at about 70%](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_7/from_date:-29,to_date:0) so that would add `iPhone 4`, `iPhone 4S`, `iPod Touch 5th Gen`, `iPad 3`, `iPad 4`, `iPad Mini`, `iPhone 5`, `iPhone 5s`, and `iPhone 5c` to your test device matrix. The majority of the remaining 30% will be iOS 6.0/6.1 which adds `iPhone 3GS` and `iPod Touch 4th Gen` into the test device matrix.

Comment: @JetB Mixpanel also have a [graph of iPhone model distribution](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/iphone_models). Testing on `iPhone 4`, `iPhone 4S` and `iPhone 5` will cover about 92% of the iPhone market.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are interested in market shares of Android, then go to the play developer console, create an app and take a look at the statistics. It will show you which versions of android are most used in the category that you set for your app. To get an idea of what phones are most used, take a look at this chart http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-phones Testing on some of these and some lower end phones should be satisfying.

In case of iOS for graphics performance, test on a iPhone 4. That has retina display but not very good GPU. If that performs well, then it will do well everywhere.

Otherwise, regarding any mobile stuff, test on any device that satisfies the requirements of your application. Test for screen size and performance if that is crucial.

i* resolutions: http://www.iosres.com/
Android resolutions: don't suppose anything, plan for flexibility

Once you are Ok with what you see on your device and in the simulator, then go ahead and start a private beta with TestFlight, Hockey App or any other platform.

In general, everything depends on your app. Whether it has hardware needs or should work on any device, or only with OS versions above some level... The definitive answer depends on your exact requirements. There is no holy grail and you should rather plan the way you'll handle any issues.